# Uninstall xcode 4.5 (iOS 6)

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

Just realised I've made a mistake of updating xcode 4.5 (iOS 6) as it causing problems.

**How to uninstall xcode 4.5 (iOS 6)? safely? as iOS 6 is beta.** I want to go back to xcode 5.1.

Comment: I have upgraded my both work and home Macs to Xcode 4.5 and all works fine. It might be easier to share your problems with the new version than struggling with downgrade.

Comment: Yes I understand. I'd rather to get to know xcode the one I'm already familiar before moving on. It is pain in the a*ss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**iOS6 is no longer beta.** So if you installed Xcode 4.5 from the store, you already have the release version of Xcode 4.5. If not, get it from the store.

If you want an older version of Xcode, look [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode).

Comment: I just don't want iOS6 as I've new problems that I don't know enough. As I'm new to xcode and until then I'll just stick with iOS5.1

Comment: Just note, that if you have installed iOS6 on a device, you will not be able to restore back to iOS5.1.1. If you are working with the simulator, you can download the iOS 5.1 SDK and simulator, and work with those. There is no need to switch Xcode.

Comment: To **uninstall**, open Launchpad, hold clicked on Xcode and click the X button to remove it. Then download an old Xcode and use that.

Comment: I've just stopped the iOS6 install on my iPhone device after the go ahead within few seconds with my last minute hunch!!!

Comment: You should be moving ahead with the times. iOS6 is here to stay, and since you are just starting developing, there is no reason why you should learn working with an older version, especially with new language features available for Objective C on iOS in Xcode 4.5 and its compiler. Try posting your problems so we can help.

Comment: Yes I see your point I'm using Phonegap/HTML5 (not using Objective C) I don't see the point unless it is beneficial for Phonegap/HTML5?

Comment: @Leo Natan. How do I download the older SDK version? I have been searching for quite sometime and I seem to be stuck with this small issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where you may not want to upgrade to the latest version of Xcode.

In my company there are still customers with iPhone 3 that are running iOS 4.2.1 and Xcode 4.5 won't generate code for it. Xcode will generate for 4.3 upwards.

Surprisingly I have an iPhone 3 (A1303) that has been upgraded to iOS 6.0 and Xcode won't generate code for that either.

So, for those that do need to downgrade, you use the link that @leo posted to get hold of the dmg for the version of Xcode you want (4.4.1 probably) and mount it. You then find the existing Xcode (in your application folder) and drag it to the waste bin, then drag the downgraded Xcode to the application folder. You may need to re-install the command line tools, if you use them. Make sure you get the version for your Mac's OS.